# How do I run a virtual server on same IP of main server but different port using Cherokee?

Tags: django, cherokee, virtual-server

When I have installed a Cherokee server and I only have one IP address, I need to know how to create a virtual server that can access for example with:

```
MY_SAME_IP_CHEROKEE:7000
```

I just want to change the port and I want to be able to create any virtual server with Cherokee using the same IP but a different **port**.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the ports that the Cherokee server will listen to using the 'General' configuration settings within `cherokee-admin`. After starting `cherokee-admin` click onto the `General` icon at the top of the screen, click the `Ports to listen` tab and add your additional ports.  Once you've done this, then you're able to configure or add your virtual servers accordingly via the `vServers` icon at the top of the screen and associate these with the given IP address or hostname you're using.

By default, all virtual servers can potentially be used against the ports you configure Cherokee to listen on.  So, you may want to configure rules for your virtual server behaviors to check the incoming IP address or port accordingly.